# Why does NearestNeighbors (SKlearn) take more time when n_neighbors is less than total number of items?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, similarity, nearest-neighbor

I want to calculate top 20 similar items for each of **N** items in the dataset.
Each item is represented using features of **M** dimensions Thus the data size is **N_items X M_features**.

When I don't specify `n_neighbors` (default value is 5), `kneighbors` function takes lots of time.
But when I specify `n_neighbors = N_items`, it gives results almost instantaneously.

i.e. `NN_object = NearestNeighbors()` takes lot of time to find `kneighbors` but `NN_object = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=N_items)` gives results fairly quickly.

Can anyone explains what exactly happening behind the scene?

PS: `N_items` in my case is **~50K** and `M_features` is **~10K**.

Comment: Wait what? `len(features)` is equal to what *exactly*?

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/neighbors/base.py#L269   link for k-neighbor function